# How get a field contains which at least two matching words from other table in clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I would like to get results from the fields (path) in table URL where the last directory in the path field from URL table contains at least two matching words from the same row in the Locations table.

**Table URL**

```
WITH arrayJoin([
    ('/directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm', 0 ),
    ('/directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm', 1 ),
    ('/directory1/london-moscow.htm', 2),
    ('/directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm', 3),
    ('/directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm', 4 ),
    ('/directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm', 5),
    ('/directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow', 6)] )as data
SELECT data.1 as path,data.2 as value
```

### Table

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm | 0 |
| /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm | 1 |
| /directory1/london-moscow.htm | 2 |
| /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm | 3 |
| /directory1/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm | 4 |
| /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm | 5 |

### Table Locations

```
WITH arrayJoin([
    ('paris','row 1'),
    ('oslo','row 2'),
    ('granada','row 3'),
    ('ny-paris-milan-granada','row 4'),
    ('london-moscow','row 5'),
    ('lisboa','row 6'),
    ('ny-aaaa-milan','row 7'),
    ('berlin-moscow-keyword3','row 8')] )as data
SELECT data.1 as location_name,data.2 as row_number
```

### Table Locations

| location_name | row_number |
| --- | --- |
| paris | 1 |
| oslo | 2 |
| granada | 3 |
| ny-paris-milan-granada | 4 |
| london-moscow | 5 |
| lisboa | 6 |
| ny-aaaa-milan | 7 |
| berlin-moscow-keyword3 | 8 |

### My sql

I try this SQL but dowcounts each keyword if exists in any rows, not in the same row

```
WITH  arrayFlatten(groupUniqArray(splitByNonAlpha(arrayJoin([
    ('paris','row 1'),
    ('oslo','row 2'),
    ('granada','row 3'),
    ('ny-paris-milan-granada','row 4'),
    ('london-moscow','row 5'),
    ('lisboa','row 6'),
    ('ny-aaaa-milan','row 7'),
    ('berlin-moscow-keyword3','row 8')] ).1))) as location_namee
SELECT arrayJoin([
    ('/directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm', 0 ),
    ('/directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm', 1 ),
    ('/directory1/london-moscow.htm', 2),
    ('/directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm', 3),
    ('/directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm', 4 ),
    ('/directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm', 5),
    ('/directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow', 6)] ).1 as path,
    splitByNonAlpha(replaceRegexpAll(path,'^\/(.*)\/(.*)\.htm$',    '\\2')) as words_in_directory,
    arrayFilter(x -> has(location_namee,x),words_in_directory) as matchedWords
```

### Result of my sql (not result desired)

| path | words_in_directory | matchedWords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm | ['paris','oslo','london'] | ['paris','oslo','london'] |
| /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm | ['paris','oslo','granada'] | ['paris','oslo','granada'] |
| /directory1/london-moscow.htm | ['london','moscow'] | ['london','moscow'] |
| /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm | ['barcelona','moscow'] | ['moscow'] |
| /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm | ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london'] | ['lisboa','london'] |
| /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm | ['ny','anykeyword','milan'] | ['ny','milan'] |
| /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow | ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] | ['berlin','milan','moscow'] |

### Results desired

| url | match | number_of_elements_matching_in_url | matchedWords | row_matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm | yes | 2 | 'paris','granada' | row 4 |
| directory3/ny-anykeyword-otherkeyword-milan.htm | yes | 2 | 'ny','milan' | row 7 |
| directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow | yes | 2 | 'berlin','moscow' | row 8 |
| directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm | not | 1 | '-' | - |
| directory1/london-moscow.htm | yes | 2 | 'london','moscow' | row 5 |
| directory1/paris-oslo-london. | not | 1 | '-' | - |
| directory1/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm | not | 1 | '-' | - |

Comment: Sorry by format in tables, I don't know why shows error if add more lines (lines unformatted below the tables)

Comment: I don't see any logic in desired result. How number_of_elements_matching_in_url =1 in two last lines but matchedWords =   '-' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong here?

```sql
select path, value, length(matchedWords) number_of_elements_matching_in_url, words_in_directory, matchedWords, row_number
from (
WITH ((splitByNonAlpha((arrayJoin([
    ('paris','row 1'),
    ('oslo','row 2'),
    ('granada','row 3'),
    ('ny-paris-milan-granada','row 4'),
    ('london-moscow','row 5'),
    ('lisboa','row 6'),
    ('ny-aaaa-milan','row 7'),
    ('berlin-moscow-keyword3','row 8')]) as data1).1)),data1.2) as data
select path, value, splitByNonAlpha(replaceRegexpAll(path,'^\/(.*)\/(.*)\.htm$',    '\\2')) as words_in_directory,
       data.1 location_name, data.2 as row_number,
       arrayIntersect( words_in_directory, data.1 ) matchedWords
  from 
    (WITH arrayJoin([
        ('/directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm', 0 ),
        ('/directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm', 1 ),
        ('/directory1/london-moscow.htm', 2),
        ('/directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm', 3),
        ('/directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm', 4 ),
        ('/directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm', 5),
        ('/directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow', 6)] )as datax
    SELECT datax.1 as path, datax.2 as value)
) 
order by row_number

┌─path────────────────────────────────────────────┬─value─┬─number_of_elements_matching_in_url─┬─words_in_directory────────────────────────────────────┬─matchedWords────────┬─row_number─┐
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  0 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ []                  │ row 1      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  0 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ []                  │ row 1      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  0 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ []                  │ row 1      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  0 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ []                  │ row 1      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  0 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ []                  │ row 1      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  1 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ ['paris']           │ row 1      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  1 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ ['paris']           │ row 1      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  0 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ []                  │ row 2      │
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  0 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ []                  │ row 2      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  1 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ ['oslo']            │ row 2      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  0 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ []                  │ row 2      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  0 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ []                  │ row 2      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  1 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ ['oslo']            │ row 2      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  0 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ []                  │ row 2      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  1 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ ['granada']         │ row 3      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  0 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ []                  │ row 3      │
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  0 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ []                  │ row 3      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  0 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ []                  │ row 3      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  0 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ []                  │ row 3      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ []                  │ row 3      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  0 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ []                  │ row 3      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  2 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ ['paris','granada'] │ row 4      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  2 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ ['ny','milan']      │ row 4      │
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  1 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ ['milan']           │ row 4      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  1 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ ['paris']           │ row 4      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  0 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ []                  │ row 4      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  0 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ []                  │ row 4      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  0 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ []                  │ row 4      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  1 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ ['moscow']          │ row 5      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  2 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ ['moscow','london'] │ row 5      │
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  1 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ ['moscow']          │ row 5      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  1 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ ['london']          │ row 5      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  0 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ []                  │ row 5      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ []                  │ row 5      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  1 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ ['london']          │ row 5      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  0 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ []                  │ row 6      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  0 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ []                  │ row 6      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  1 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ ['lisboa']          │ row 6      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ []                  │ row 6      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  0 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ []                  │ row 6      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ []                  │ row 6      │
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  0 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ []                  │ row 6      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  0 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ []                  │ row 7      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ []                  │ row 7      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  0 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ []                  │ row 7      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  2 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ ['ny','milan']      │ row 7      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ []                  │ row 7      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  0 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ []                  │ row 7      │
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  1 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ ['milan']           │ row 7      │
│ /directory2/keyword1-keyword2-lisboa-london.htm │     4 │                                  0 │ ['keyword1','keyword2','lisboa','london']             │ []                  │ row 8      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-granada.htm              │     1 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','granada']                            │ []                  │ row 8      │
│ /directory1/london-moscow.htm                   │     2 │                                  1 │ ['london','moscow']                                   │ ['moscow']          │ row 8      │
│ /directory3/ny-anykeyword-milan.htm             │     5 │                                  0 │ ['ny','anykeyword','milan']                           │ []                  │ row 8      │
│ /directory1/paris-oslo-london.htm               │     0 │                                  0 │ ['paris','oslo','london']                             │ []                  │ row 8      │
│ /directory1/barcelona-moscow.htm                │     3 │                                  1 │ ['barcelona','moscow']                                │ ['moscow']          │ row 8      │
│ /directory3/anykeyword-berlin-milan-moscow      │     6 │                                  2 │ ['directory3','anykeyword','berlin','milan','moscow'] │ ['moscow','berlin'] │ row 8      │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┴────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: It's works fine! Thanks Denny!!